# Absolute element going behind sticky/fixed element

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I have a simple **Dropdown** and a sticky container to the right. The dropdown keeps going behind the sticky container as such:

[image]

I tried:

- changing the right container to position fixed
- changing z-index of both divs

The dropdown with position absolute is `article-actions-dropdown-content`
The sticky container is `right-sidebar-container`.

Sticky element:

```css
.right-sidebar-container {
    height: 550px;
    width: 98%;
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 20%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: sticky;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Absolute element:

```css
.article-actions-dropdown-content {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto; 
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    border-radius: 4px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `z-index: 1` to the element with class `article-actions-dropdown-wrapper`.That is,

```
.article-actions-dropdown-wrapper{
  z-index: 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tried on your codopen, the dropdown menu is nested inside the wrapper that is nested already, just apply the z-index:1000; on the .article-actions-dropdown-wrapper and z-index:0; on .right-sidebar-container

z-index use to start the unit count of a nested element 100 or 10 (don't remember) unit less compared to an higher one then you have to insert higher numbers

Answer (score 0):

You should take z-index:1 for the class .article-actions-dropdown-content because it will prioritize the sticky menu.